# C - Program that reads from file.txt only odd lines

Tags: c, arrays, file

i have a problem with implementation of program, that will have 3 functions: void read(char *file name(program will read from that file and print text from lines with odd number in terminal)...), void write(char *file_name1(program will write number of characters from lines that have odd number from input file), char *file_name2(program will write in binary number of characters from lines - from input file - that have odd number)...) and main that will have names of these files as arguments. Then i will be able to start the program using something like this: ./a.out input.txt output.txt output.bin
In main function i have char array[10][80]. In summary, i want to read first 10 lines from input file .txt, then write in terminal the lines with odd index, then save number of characters (as text and binary) in these lines in two files: .txt and .bin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10
#define M 80


void read(char *file_name){
FILE *file_name;
file_name=fopen(".txt", "r");
char tab[80];
if (input==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(-1);
        }
while(!feof(input)){
    fgets(tab, 80, input);
 }
}

void write(){
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char TEKST[N][M];
read(argv[1]);
write(argv[2], argv[3]);

return 0;
}
```

This is the code i have started writing. I don't know how to pass input file name to fopen function as an argument, how to print in terminal only lines with text with odd index from input file. And how to count characters from these lines and save them to 2 files: .txt and .bin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! And your question is...? ...[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post the code you have already written.

Comment: Where does one start? 1. `FILE *file_name;` - Using the same variable name as the argument to the function. 2. Not checking the return value - Have you opened the file? 3 Are you sure that the file that you wish to open is called `.txt`. Calling the function `read` when this is used for io. 4. `input` - Where is this declared? 5. Does this compile.....

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine you would get the first line, put it into your output string, then get the next line and discard it. Repeat that until the file ends.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //open the file
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    //the max number of characters per line
    const int maxCharsPerLine = 100; //you can change this number to whatever you want

    //the maximum amout of characters you want on the output
    const int maxOutputChars = 1000; //you can change this number to whatever you want

    //a c string to hold a single line of data at a time
    char currLine[maxCharsPerLine];

    //a c string to hold the odd lines of data
    char oddLines[maxOutputChars];
    memset(oddLines, 0, sizeof(oddLines));

//a c string to hold the even lines of data
char evenLines[maxCharsPerLine];

//while you are not at the end of the file
while (/*get a line of characters*/ fgets(currLine, maxCharsPerLine, file) != NULL)
{
    //update the line of characters
    strcat(oddLines, currLine);

    //discard a line of characters
    fgets(evenLines, maxCharsPerLine, file);
    memset(evenLines, 0, sizeof(evenLines));
}
fclose(file);

//print the odd lines
printf("%s", oddLines);
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua - welcome to StackOverflow. Based on the way this question is written, I think this user will need some help with the code itself rather than just the algorithm. If you can help with that (bearing in mind the comments on the question) then please do.